# C need help understanding pointer iteration

Tags: c

So I'm trying to learn some C with pointers but I'm having trouble understanding the following code snippet. first and last are the first and last item. So you have something like first, middle, last. but what is last - 1? Is it just the second last element? so if we have some thing first, last with no middle then this would be true?

```
item *first, item *last
if (first == last -1)
    return 0
```

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic.  It's hard to know what it's actually doing without more context, but I doubt this code does anything useful.

Comment: Are first and last pointing at elements of an array? I don't think there is any guarantee that last-1 is anything useful otherwise.

Comment: The code as is doesn't compile (it's lacking semicolons). In order to avoid confusion it's always best to copy and paste actual, working code. In cases like this some surrounding code would provide context which determines whether the comparison makes sense and the subtraction is allowed. Optimally the code would be a minimal example, e.g. a function and a short main() calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have an array of `item`:

```
item arr[10];
```

and then you set `first` and `last` to point to the first and last items of the array, respectively:

```
item *first = &arr[0];
item *last  = &arr[9];
```

which gives us something like

```
           item          item *
     +---+ 
arr: |   | arr[0] <----  first
     +---+
     |   | arr[1]
     +---+  
     |   | arr[2]
     +---+
      ...
     +---+
     |   | arr[8] <----  last - 1
     +---+
     |   | arr[9] <----  last
     +---+
```

The expression `last - 1` gives you a pointer to the object immediately before the object pointed to by `last`, *assuming both objects are members of the same array*, or that `last` points to an object immediately following the end of the array.

C doesn't guarantee that individual variables are laid out in any specific order, so adding or subtracting an offset to a pointer only works (that is, gives you a useful result) if you're pointing to an element of an array.  IOW, if you had something like

```
item a;
item b;

item *first = &a;
item *last = &b;
```

then the expression `last - 1` isn't guaranteed to point to `a` (nor is `first + 1` guaranteed to point to `b`).

Answer (score 0):

To expound on @John Bode's answer, a pointer is just a number. It's an address in memory. Arrays are laid out contiguously in memory. The first element has the lowest address, and the last element the highest address.

So, if we have the address for the first element in the array, and we add 1, we get the memory address of the next element in the array. Your compiler *should* know how many bytes each element in the array takes up unless you're doing weird casting on the pointers. Knowing this, the program adds that many bytes to the address.

So, to get to the next address, we simply add 1. To get to the *previous* address, we can subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another pointer math illustration

Not knowing the type of `item` in your example code, I will choose to make it a struct:

```
  typedef struct {
      int a;
      int b;
      float c;
  } item_s;//new type
```

Using the new type `item_s`, create the following array and a set of pointers to illustrate pointer arithmetic

```
  item_s item[5] = {{1,2,3.0},{10,20,30.0},{15,25,35.0},{16,26,36.0},{17,27,37.0}};
  item_s *first, *last, *index;
  //set the `first` and `last` pointers to the first and last element of the array
  first = &item[0];
  last  = &item[4];
  
  //now illustrate type of pointer manipulation and its results
  index = first + 1 ;// index now points to the area of memory occupied by item[1]
          // first + 1*sizeof(item_s)
   printf("a: %d\nb: %d\nc:%f\n", index->a, index->b, index->c);
  index = last - 1;//index points to the area of memory occupied by item[3]
          // last - 1*sizeof(item_s)
   printf("a: %d\nb: %d\nc:%f\n", index->a, index->b, index->c);
  index = last + 1;//index points to an un-owned area of memory and possibly a seg-fault.
    //printf("a: %d\nb: %d\nc:%f\n", index->a, index->b, index->c);//UB
```

So when you increment a pointer by `1`, the new memory location pointed to is exactly the
*old memory location* + 1 `*` sizeof(pointer type)
If you increment it by 3, then it is
*old memory location* + 3 `*` sizeof(pointer type)